# Why is git pull not updating my branch, when git status shows new files?

Tags: windows, git, azure-devops

I have a branch `feature/foo` checked out, and there are some new commits available:

```
> git status
On branch feature/foo
Your branch is behind 'origin/feature/foo' by 42 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

But when I run `git pull`, I get a weird error:

```
> git pull
remote: Azure Repos
remote: Found 7 objects to send. (1371 ms)
Unpacking objects: 100% (7/7), 624 bytes | 18.00 KiB/s, done.
From https://microsoft.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/FOO/_git/FooRepo
   fda4afcb2c..9bb69c8822  bla -> origin/bla
warning: fetch normally indicates which branches had a forced update,
but that check has been disabled; to re-enable, use '--show-forced-updates'
flag or run 'git config fetch.showForcedUpdates true'
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/feature/foo'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

> Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/feature/foo'
> from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.

Why can't I git pull?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a casing issue. The branch was named `feature/FOO` online. Changing the case of the remote worked:

```
> git branch -u origin/feature/FOO
> git pull
warning: fetch normally indicates which branches had a forced update,
but that check has been disabled; to re-enable, use '--show-forced-updates'
flag or run 'git config fetch.showForcedUpdates true'
Updating 2e33fff796..19fb4f2d86
# ...
```